# Trying to save values from html to javascript array but it isn't working

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, list

So I made a list in html and gave every option a value of numbers (0,1,2,...) and gave all the options the same class 'op' and then I want to save this values in an array in javascript but my code doesn't seem to work.

output should be [0,1,2,3,...]
instead nothing happens

```
    let valuesofnames = [];
    let valuesfromhtml = document.getElementsByClassName('op').value;
    valuesofnames.push(valuesfromhtml);
    console.log(valuesofnames)
```

Comment: As far as I know one cannot simply push an array into an array. You'll probably want to run array.sliice(); or in your case const valuesofnames = valuesfromhtml.slice();

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns a `NodeList`. You need to loop over the list.

Comment: ```let valuesfromhtml = document.getElementsByClassName('op');

const valuesofnames = 
Object.keys(valuesfromhtml).map((key) => valuesfromhtml[key].value);
console.log(valuesofnames)```.

Comment: can you explain your code more specifically please zain zafar

Comment: why does it return a nodelist and why doesn't it store the values @Barmar

Comment: What should it return instead? You asked for all the elements with that class, not just a single element. Each element in the collection can have a different value, so what do you expect `.value` to return?

Comment: Doesn't the linked question explain this?

Comment: I expect it to return the values of all classes having the same class name

Comment: I changed my code according to the question you directed me to and here is what i made                                                                                                                               
       `let valuesfromhtml = document.getElementsByClassName('op').value;
        function test(value){
            for (i=0 ; i < valuesfromhtml ; i++){
                let valuesofnames = [];
                valuesofnames.push(valuesfromhtml);
                console.log(valuesofnames)
            }
        }`

Comment: here i tried to make a loop and save the value in the order of how the loop go and yet it doesn't do anything

Comment: I just wanted to thank you for giving me your time to answer my questions.